# Sprite-Kit Change Image of Node when screen gets touched

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, uitouch, skspritenode

There is a hero that is controlled by tapping on the screen. I want the hero too look a little different every time the screen gets touched.

What I did is setting up two images that are a little different. I want the image of the hero to be changed when there is a touch event.

Until now I set up an array to save the information in but it kinda won't work out:

```
 NSMutableArray *heroFrames = [NSMutableArray array];

NSString* textureName = nil;

if (UITouchPhaseBegan) {
    textureName = @"hero1.gif";
}
else  {
    textureName = @"hero2.gif";
}

    SKTexture* texture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:textureName];
    [heroFrames addObject:texture];

[self setHeroFrames:HeroFrames];

self.hero = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:[_heroFrames objectAtIndex:1]];
```

I get an exception when running this.. Any other idea how to achieve my problem?

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Welcome to SO.

Try this code:

```
#import "MyScene.h"

@implementation MyScene
{
    BOOL myBool;
    SKSpriteNode *hero;
    SKTexture *texture1;
    SKTexture *texture2;
}

-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size
{
    if (self = [super initWithSize:size])
    {
        myBool = false;
        texture1 = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"hero1.gif"];
        texture2 = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"hero2.gif"];
        hero = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:texture1];
        hero.position = CGPointMake(200, 150);
        [self addChild:hero];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if(myBool == true)
    {
        hero.texture = texture1;
        myBool = false;
    } else
    {
        hero.texture = texture2;
        myBool = true;
    }
}
```